# Three.js set the center of a Object3D based on internal meshes

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh set that is in a Object3D when i get the vertices they are not centered on the object. so i need to compute the center of the object3D then move the meshes to align them to the center. I have tried computing the boundingboxes of each Mesh then max - min /2; this does not work. Any help here would be fantastic. I have tried the Object3D.setFromObject(); this only return infinity.

Comment: Can you share some code? A bit hard to visualise your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center an Object3D, depending on its children, you have to iterate through them, as far as I know. The code would look like the following:

```js
// myObject3D is your Object3D

var children = myObject3D.children,
  completeBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(); // create a new box which will contain the entire values

for(var i = 0, j = children.length; i < j; i++){ // iterate through the children

  children[i].geometry.computeBoundingBox(); // compute the bounding box of the the meshes geometry

  var box = children[i].geometry.boundingBox.clone(); // clone the calculated bounding box, because we have to translate it

  box.translate(children[i].position); // translate the geometries bounding box by the meshes position

  completeBoundingBox.addPoint(box.max).addPoint(box.min); // add the max and min values to your completeBoundingBox

}

var objectCenter = completeBoundingBox.center()

console.log('This is the center of your Object3D:', objectCenter );

// You want the center of you bounding box to be at 0|0|0

myObject3D.position.x -= objectCenter.x;
myObject3D.position.y -= objectCenter.y;
myObject3D.position.z -= objectCenter.z;
```

Hope I understood your problem right!

Answer (score 0):

```
center = function(obj) {
  var children = obj.children,
  completeBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
  for(var i = 0, j = children.length; i < j; i++) {
    children[i].geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var box = children[i].geometry.boundingBox.clone();
    box.translate(children[i].position);
    completeBoundingBox.set(box.max, box.min);
  }
  var objectCenter = completeBoundingBox.center()
  console.log('This is the center of your Object3D:', objectCenter );
  obj.position.x -= objectCenter.x;
  obj.position.y -= objectCenter.y;
  obj.position.z -= objectCenter.z;
}
```

Comment: can you add comments to explain what's your code doing?

Comment: center(obj)

obj -- Object3D -- the object3D to show the world-axis-aligned boundingbox.

This center the Object3D.